# Rational point in the sense of Serre

Tags: algebraic-curves, algebraic-groups

In Serre's *Algebraic groups and class fields* Chapter V.1, he gave the following definition of a point $P$ rational over a field $K$:

We first fix a base field $k$ that is algebraically closed and $X$ is a nonsingular projective irreducible algebraic curve defined over $k$. Make a choice of a universal domain $\Omega$; this is an algebraically closed extension of $k$ of infinite transcendence degree over $k$. And then he wrote

> By a *point* of $X$, we mean a point $P$ all of whose coordinates belong to $\Omega$; if we denote by $k(P)$ the field generated over $k$ by these coordinates, $k(P)$ is an extension of finite type over $k$. One says that $P$ is rational over a field $K$ if $k(P) \subset K$.

How does this compare to the usual definition that a $K$-rational point of $X$ implies that we have a morphism $\mathrm{Spec}\, K \rightarrow X$? Or is this a different concept totally?